# There's a problem about Flink's timeWindow of DataStream[For Help]

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am a beginner of Flink. I can implement Flink streaming. I also practiced the timeWindow about KeyedStream. Now I want to use Flink's timeWindow about DataStream to implement batch operations. I tried some code, But it just doesn't work. I have no idea how to achieve the desired effect.

```
val resultDataStream: DataStream[HBaseOperation] = env
  .addSource(kafkaUserEventSource)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new Launcher.CustomWatermarkExtractor(Time.hours(24)))
  .flatMap { line =>
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val tableInfo: mutable.Buffer[TableInfo] = JSON.parseArray(line.columnValueList, classOf[TableInfo]).asScala
    line.eventType match {
      case EventType.INSERT => tableInfo.map {
        row => HBaseOperation(line.eventType, s"${line.dbName}.${line.tableName}", HBASE_CFNAME, tableInfo(0).columnValue, row.columnName, row.columnValue)
      }
      case EventType.UPDATE => tableInfo.filter(_.isValid).map {
        row => HBaseOperation(line.eventType, s"${line.dbName}.${line.tableName}", HBASE_CFNAME, tableInfo(0).columnValue, row.columnName, row.columnValue)
      }
      case EventType.DELETE => List(HBaseOperation(line.eventType, s"${line.dbName}.${line.tableName}", HBASE_CFNAME, tableInfo(0).columnValue, null, null))
    }
  }
resultDataStream.print()//Here it works

//batch operations
val value: AllWindowedStream[HBaseOperation, TimeWindow] = resultDataStream.timeWindowAll(Time.seconds(5))
val resultDataStream2: DataStream[BatchHBaseOperation] = value.apply(new RichAllWindowFunction[HBaseOperation, BatchHBaseOperation, TimeWindow] {
  override def apply(window: TimeWindow, input: Iterable[HBaseOperation], out: Collector[BatchHBaseOperation]): Unit = {
    val ops: ListBuffer[HBaseOperation] = ListBuffer[HBaseOperation]()
    input.foreach(op => ops += op)
    out.collect(BatchHBaseOperation(ops.toList))
  }
})//Doesn't work
resultDataStream2.print()
//resultDataStream2.addSink(HBaseUtil.putMapData(_))
env.execute("KafkaHBaseApp")
```

Answer (score 0):

The details of your watermark generator aren't clear, but if it is based on Flink's bounded out-of-orderness watermarking, then `CustomWatermarkExtractor(Time.hours(24))` means that the time window won't be triggered for the first time until 24 hours of data (plus 5 seconds) have been processed. This could explain why it doesn't appear to be working.